# rails geocoder gem - want to geocode_by :google_place_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I am using the rails geocoder gem combined with a f/e solution that sends through the google_place_id. What I would like to do is configure geocoder to geocode by the place_id. I have tried several things to tell geocoder that I am using a place_id but it fails to accept it.

Tried this

```
geocoded_by :place_id, params: {google_place_id: true}
```

and this

```
geocoded_by :place_id, google_place_id: true
```

and put the option in the initializer to no avail

I know it works as I have used this to retrieve location information

```
Geocoder.search("<PLACE ID>", {google_place_id: true})
```

How do I configure geocoder to use the google_place_id?

Comment: I haven't ever messed with your particular scenario, but have you checked out this part of the geocoder docs? https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/README_API_GUIDE.md

Comment: I did check these out initially. I wondered if I had missed something but I did add the google_place_id: true option as stated in these docs... just only seems to work when using Geocoder.search

Comment: Damn, sorry.  :(